# Run tests inside Docker container with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-compose

We want to give it a try to setup CI/CD with Jenkins for our project. The project itself has Elasticsearch and PostgreSQL as runtime dependencies and Webdriver for acceptance testing.
In dev environment, everything is set up within one `docker-compose.yml` file and we have `acceptance.sh` script to run acceptance tests.

After digging documentation I found that it's potentially possible to build CI with following steps:

1. dockerize project
2. pull project from git repo
3. somehow pull `docker-compose.yml` and project `Dockerfile` - either:

   - put it in the project repo
   - put it in separate repo (this is how it's done now)
   - put somewhere on a  server and jut copy it over
4. execute `docker-compose up`
5. project's Dockerfile will have `ONBUILT` section to run tests. Unit tests are run through `mix tests` and acceptance through `scripts/acceptance.sh`. It'll be cool to run them in parallel.
6. shutdown `docker-compose`, clean up containers

Because this is my first experience with Jenkins a series of questions arise:

- Is this a viable strategy?
- How to connect tests output with Jenkins?
- How to run and shut down docker-compose?
- Do we need/want to write a pipeline for that? Will we need/want pipeline when we will get to the CD on the next stage?

Thanks

Comment: Ye it is a viable strategy. but it requires running docker inside docker which is quite an advanced technique. You can find more information in the `Docker book` here https://www.dockerbook.com

Comment: Hi Miad! Thank you for reference, I'll for sure check out the book!
Might that plugin help in working with docker https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/chapter-docker-workflow.html ?

Comment: Haven't checked. might be worth a try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this a viable strategy?

Yes it is. I think it would be better to include the `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` in the project repo. That way any changes are tied to the version of code that uses the changes. If it's in an external repo it becomes a lot harder to change (unless you pin the git sha somehow , like using a submodule).

> project's Dockerfile will have `ONBUILD` section to run tests

I would avoid this. Just set a different command to run the tests in a container, not at build time.

> How to connect tests output with Jenkins?

Jenkins just uses the exit status from the build steps, so as long as the test script exits with a non-zero code on failure and a zero code on success that's all you need. Test output that is printed to stdout/stderr will be visible from jenkins console.

> How to run and shut down docker-compose?

I would recommend this to run Compose:

```
docker-compose pull # if you use images from the hub, pull the latest version
docker-compose up --build -d
```

In a post-build step to shutdown:

```
docker-compose down --volumes
```

> Do we need/want to write a pipeline for that?

No, I think just a single job is fine. Get it working with a simple setup first, and then you can figure out what you need to split into different jobs.

Comment: "Jenkins just uses the exit status from the build steps, so as long as the test script exits with a non-zero code on failure and a zero code on success that's all you need. Test output that is printed to stdout/stderr will be visible from jenkins console." 

I'm having an issue where an xml file is created as a side effect of running tests, but it's inside the container and need to get it out. I've tried volume mounting the directory it's created in into the jenkins workspace but it doesn't seem to be coming up. any ideas here?

Comment: I would recommend using `docker cp` for getting the file out.

Comment: But after docker run completes the container is no longer running

Comment: That's exactly how we do it, using `docker cp`. The test output (reports or anything) can be copied even from stopped containers.
So, first, run the tests inside the container, then copy the test artifacts to a location in the host with `docker cp`, and finally, perform `docker-compose down` to remove everything.
Something really important: Use a non-root user in your Dockerfile otherwise the XML file created from the tests container would have the root as owner, meaning Jenkins won't be able to delete it.